# Looping through a dataframe with and totalling up given a certain condition (R)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like the below:

[image]

I want to total up sales according to region. Below is the code I am using to total up sales for "East". I want to use the for loop and not a inbuilt function.

```
 totalEast <- 0
 for( i in 1: nrow(sales)){

    if (sales$Region[i] =="East"){

        totalEast <- sales$Total[i] + totalEast

    }
}

    print(totalEast)
```

but it is not working??
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Vectorize: `totalEast <- sum(sales$Total[sales$Region == "East"])`.

Comment: Also, don't post data as images, please. Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(sales)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(sales, 20))`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. What if I wanted to keep the code as is....with the if condition ....why is it not working....is the logic incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr:

```
sales %>% group_by(Region) %>%
summarize(byreg=sum(Total))
```